# How to do load app socket testing?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, sockets

We are handling the calling functionality through a socket connection in mobile Application, so anyone helps that know how to test the load on the socket connection? Jmeter is helpful for testing the socket connection? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a way, first Google hit on "jmeter socket testing":

> Mar 05 2016
>
> At the moment the only easy way to implement WebSocket testing with
>   JMeter is to use [JMeter WebSocket Sampler by Maciej Zaleski](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler). It's the
>   only RFC6455-compliant  extension which supports reusing one TCP
>   session and it is easy to install and use.
>
> https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter/

Alternatively I would use a xUnit framework (which uses an actual socket implementation in code) load testing tool. You should be able to figure this out with a developer that build the socket system.

- Java: A recent JUnit example for performance testing can be found here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-we-do-performance-testing-easily-efficiently-a
- C#: https://www.productivecsharp.com/2016/03/nbench-performance-testing-nunit-resharper-integration/

Comment: I have configured the TCP sampler config but in response, I can't find the response.

Comment: Okay@niels van Reijmersdal